# Visual Studio showing unexplainable error by me

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

So I was running a c# program and then I saw this in the error list section

```
Warning MSB3026 Could not copy "C:\Users\USER\source\repos\app\app\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\app.exe" to "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\app.exe". Beginning retry 10 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\app.exe' because it is being used by another process. The file is locked by: "app (11048)"  app D:\Visual Studio\main app\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   4651
```

Btw here's my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Metadata.Ecma335;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace app
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetMax(2, 1, 3));
        }
        static int GetMax(int num1, int num2, int num3 )
        {
            int result;
            if (num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3)
            {
                result = num1;
            }
            else if (num2 >= num1 && num2 >= num3)
            {
                result = num2;
            }
            else { result = num3; }
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

It says no issue is found but I still get that error message, can somebody help?
I also can't find any solution on google

Comment: Sounds like your program is already running while you compile it.

Comment: Either already ot still.

Comment: This usually means it is already running. Check for an overlooked console window somewhere. If all else fails, open task manager and look for app.exe, and kill it

Comment: Check the process on the task manager. Either kill it from there if you see it loaded and try to rerun the application or in the worst case restart the computer.

Comment: Ok I'll try it, btw thx :D